# Single variable update of an Entity using a PUT request

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have a User entity as follows:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Pattern(regexp = RegexConstants.EMAIL_REGEX, message = ValidationMessages.EMAIL_VALIDATION_MESSAGE)
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    private String countryCode;


    /* Getters and Setters */

}
```

I want to update only the country code of the user. 
I want to use the **PUT** request as that seems to be the an appropriate choice **(don't hate me for using the word appropriate here, I might be wrong)** but it seems like an over-kill to send the user in the request body as I do not intend to update anything but the country code. 
I actually do not even have the whole user when I am making a request. The user body `(@RequestBody user)` only contains `name` and `country code`.

So, based on what I've read about PUT requests, I need to send the complete user object in the request which I do not have. Now I can accomplish this by passing the country code simply in the URL but all the articles I have read on RESTful web services recommend against it.

Current Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("Updating User " + id);

        User currentUser = userService.findById(id);

        if (currentUser==null) {
            System.out.println("User with id " + id + " not found");
            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentUser.setCountryCode(user.getCountryCode);

        userService.updateUser(currentUser);
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(currentUser, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I would really appreciate if someone can guide to the right way to do this. I have read about the PATCH request but I am not sure if that is the way to go in my case. 
If I am doing it wrong it would really helpful if you can also provide an example or give me a starting point as to how to take this in the correct format.

Comment: From [RFC 5789](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789): "In a `PUT` request, the enclosed entity is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be replaced.  With `PATCH`, however, the enclosed entity contains a set of instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version." In this setting, `PATCH` seems to be more fitting.

Comment: But its not like all the parameters I am passing are dynamically being updated based on what I am passing. If I pass country code then it will be updating the country code. Similarly if I pass 'age' in the same request body it would still try to update the country code. Because that's the code written.  Does this sound like correct behavior or am I moving away from the point.

Comment: I have read some more RFC's on this matter. It seems that your particular case is somewhat exotic and against the REST principle. There are, however, some Errors defined in RFC 5789. I would return an Error 422  (Unprocessable Request).

Comment: Well then what kind of request should I use. I am sure there are many scenarios where the only a particular variable needs to be changed.

Comment: As I said: I would use a `PATCH` and return a 422, if something other than the country code ist updated. Please note that `PATCH` is atomic, i.e. in the example you gave above (country code and something else changes), I would return a 422 and not update at all.

Comment: When you say, something other than country code is updated, do you mean when something other than country code is passed? Because there is no way anything other than country code would get updated because there is no code for it.

Comment: "Similarly if I pass 'age' in the same request body it would still try to update the country code." - that is YOUR qoute. I assumed that something other than the country code could be passed in the  patchfile. Please specify your problem clearly next time.

Comment: I think there has been a mis-understanding here. Sorry about that. When I said "If I pass age it would still try to update country code" - This is true. And I don't mind that. But you see my whole issue is with sticking to RESTful rules & regulations. Since my method only updates country code, I was not sure if using PATCH or PUT was a good idea. Because if I understand correctly every variable update of User entity should not have a separate end-point. But in my case I need to update only country code. I was not happy with the way I have deployed an end-point just for one variable change.